# Ошибка при компиляции

Tags: c#

```
namespace SwitchFor
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 3; int j = 5; uint s = 0; char n;
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5");
            n = (char)Console.Read();
            switch (n)
            {
                case '1':
                    {
                        j = j - i;
                        s = s + (uint)j;
                    }
                    break;
                case '2':
                    {
                        j = j + i * 3;
                        s = s + (uint)j;
                    }
                    break;
                case '3':
                    {
                        j = j--;
                        s = s + (uint)j;
                    }
                    break;
                case '4':
                    {
                        j = (i - 5) * 2;
                        s = s + (uint)j;
                    }
                    break;
                case '5':
                    {
                        j = i + j + 1;
                        s = s + (uint)j;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    {
                        s = s + 1;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Сумма равна "+s);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Вот такая несложная программа, однако, она у меня почему-то работает неправильно.

```
Вывод должен быть таким:
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
3
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
4
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
5
Сумма равна (и какое-то число, полученное в результате этих пяти действий).
```

Comment: Почему ты так решил?)

Comment: Если ты имеешь ввиду то, как я выбрал метки, то это рандомно. Их можно по-другому выбрать. Но и по-другому тоже неправильно работает. Попробуй сделать эту программу на c# и увидишь, что получается.

Comment: И что можно увидеть, т.е. что неправильно? Как вообще должен проходить диалог? Попробуйте выводить после ввода n и убедитесь, что всё нормально. Возможно строка ввода n должна выглядеть примерно как `n = Console.ReadLine()[0];` ?

Comment: Из вашего вопроса непонятно, что должно было быть и что реально есть. В любом случае, если программа выполняется, то ошибки компиляции нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените, как вам писали выше, строку:

```
n = (char)Console.Read();
```

на:

```
n = Console.ReadLine()[0];
```

и ваш цикл отработает корректно.

Цитата из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.read(v=vs.90).aspx):

> Возврат управления методом `Read`
>   блокируется до ввода входных символов
>   с клавиатуры; метод возвращает
>   управление после нажатия пользователем
>   клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd>. В ответ на нажатие
>   клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd> во входные данные
>   добавляется зависящая от платформы
>   последовательность символов,
>   идентифицирующая конец строки
>   (например, в Windows добавляется
>   последовательность символов "возврат
>   каретки"-"перевод строки").
>   Последующие вызовы метода `Read`
>   извлекают пользовательский ввод по
>   одному символу за раз. После
>   извлечения последнего символа метод
>   `Read` снова блокирует возврат
>   управления и цикл повторяется.

Answer (score 0):

Да я неправильно сформулировал. Вывод есть но вместо нужного(см. вверху) выходит такой:

```
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2
Введите метку 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
3
Сумма равна 16
```